# Align to center two elements in a row in ionic v3

Tags: css, ionic-framework

hello I have two ion toggle with their respective labels separated by columns in a row.
It looks like this:

[image: row whit elements]

How can I make both are in the center of the screen?
This is my code:

```
<ion-label class="titleFiltros" text-center>Filtrar por estado</ion-label>
<ion-list>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label>Activa</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle item-start [(ngModel)]="activa" (ionChange)="change()"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label>Anulada</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle item-start [(ngModel)]="anulada" (ionChange)="change()"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Try this`

```
<ion-label class="titleFiltros" text-center>Filtrar por estado</ion-label>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col class="ion-text-end">
            <ion-item lines="none" style="float: right;">
              Activa
              <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-item lines="none">
              Anulada
              <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, maybe because I'm using ionic version 3, I still appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it works as I expected
Here I leave the code:

```
  ion-item{
        .input-wrapper{
            flex:none;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        ion-toggle{
            margin-right:auto!important;
          }
    }
```